# Java service looses a connection to Rabbitmq and throws a NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, rabbitmq, amqp

I have a java service that works with Rabbitmq server, it gets tasks and send answers to the queue. However, after 334 handling to the Rabbitmq queue connection looses and throw nullPointerException. I can not understand why after long time working service looses connection to Rabbitmq.

How error looks

```
 [1;31mERROR[0;39m - Consumer com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN$4@59ef17e4 (amq.ctag-_itVmRHd4yWS6gG-Gh4XqQ) method handleDelivery for channel AMQChannel(amqp://guest@0.0.0.0:5672/,1) threw an exception for channel AMQChannel(amqp://guest@0.0.0.0:5672/,1)
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.peterservice.artifactory.deployPlugins.RabbitWorker.getSenderChannel(RabbitWorker.java:1364)
    at com.peterservice.artifactory.deployPlugins.RabbitWorker.lambda$runWorker$0(RabbitWorker.java:269)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN$4.handleDelivery(ChannelN.java:1404)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ConsumerDispatcher$5.run(ConsumerDispatcher.java:149)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ConsumerWorkService$WorkPoolRunnable.run(ConsumerWorkService.java:104)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

Where error happens

```
private static Channel getSenderChannel(Connection connection) throws IOException {
    Channel channel = connection.createChannel();
    channel.queueDeclare(settings.deployDoneQueue(), durable, false, false, null);
    return channel;
}
```

I made a load testing and understood that this error happens every time after 334 counts that service connects to Rabbitmq.

Comment: Each time you are opening a new channel and keeping it alive, that's why you run out of space in your connection pool. You should define your channel as a singleton or a spring bean or close it properly each time.

Comment: do you use 1 connection for whole app?